# Get nested Arrays in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, jbuilder

I have an object (Institution) and I want to get the 2 arrays (marks and attachments) that are relationed with this object using JSON.

**To be clear**: For 1 institution, I have 3 marks and for every mark I have an attachment.

Here's my code of `JSON` file:

```
if @data['admin_institution']
    json.extract! @data['admin_institution'], :id, :name, :phone, :address, :site, :created_at, :updated_at
    if @data['admin_institution'].marks
        json.marks @data['admin_institution'].marks
        json.array!(@data['admin_institution'].marks) do | admin_mark|
            json.attachment admin_mark.attachment
        end
    end

else
    json.set! :response do
        json.set! :error, 'Not Found!'
    end
end
```

I want to reproduce something like this:

```
{
   id: 14,
   name: "Ins3",
   phone: "793215-2555",
   address: "lreewrwklkr",
   site: "lkerlke.com",
   created_at: "2016-03-01T14:00:37.000-03:00",
   updated_at: "2016-03-01T14:00:37.000-03:00",
   - marks: [
      - {
           id: 17,
           admin_attachment_id: 927,
           admin_bookmark_id: 3,
           admin_institution_id: 14,
           created_at: "2016-03-01T14:00:37.000-03:00",
           updated_at: "2016-03-01T14:00:37.000-03:00"
        },
        {
           id: 18,
           admin_attachment_id: 945,
           admin_bookmark_id: 1,
           admin_institution_id: 14,
           created_at: "2016-03-01T14:00:37.000-03:00",
           updated_at: "2016-03-01T14:00:37.000-03:00"
        }
      ],
   - attachment: {
         id: 927,
         name: "nature-16",
         title: "Nature-16",
         description: null,
         mime_type: "image/jpeg",
         url: "/uploads/nature-16.jpg",
         created_at: "2016-02-29T09:21:09.000-03:00",
         updated_at: "2016-02-29T09:21:09.000-03:00"
     }   
}
```

Instead, I'm getting only the values of the last `array` (attachment). Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I used [`through-association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) on my institution model then I could get the attachments "directly" through the marks, without do a `loop` of marks. The following `code` is giving me almost all that I want.

```
if @data['admin_institution']
    json.extract! @data['admin_institution'], :id, :name, :phone, :address, :site, :created_at, :updated_at, :marks, :attachments

else
    json.set! :response do
        json.set! :error, 'Not Found!'
    end
end
```

It's returning the Institution, the marks and the attachments, **BUT** not nested. I want marks inside the institution and attachments inside the marks. How can I make it work?

Comment: I use `jbuilder` to generate JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if @data['admin_institution']
    ...
    if @data['admin_institution'].marks
        json.marks @data['admin_institution'].marks do | admin_mark|
            json.attachment admin_mark.attachment
        end
    end

else
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the marks didn't came.
`
{
id: 15,
name: "kjerkerkjer",
phone: "793215-2555",
address: "kjasdkjadkjaskjd",
site: "oedkf.com",
created_at: "2016-03-02T11:15:15.000-03:00",
updated_at: "2016-03-02T11:15:15.000-03:00",
marks: [
{
attachment: {
id: 1101,
name: "nature-24",
title: "Nature-24",
description: null,
mime_type: "image/jpeg",
url: "/uploads/nature-24.jpg",
admin_attachment_id: null,
admin_image_size_id: null,
created_at: "2016-03-02T11:06:10.000-03:00",
updated_at: "2016-03-02T11:06:10.000-03:00"
}
}
]
}
`

Comment: @developer033 Check your if clause.

Comment: There's no error in my `if`clause, I already remove it to see what happens, but nothing changes. `JSON` is just returning the institution and the marks.